# Using ReportViewe Control in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reportviewer

I'm asp.net mvc for my project and now I have to show a couple of reports using the ReportViewer control. I need to specify a couple of properties before rendering the report ie. ReportServer Url.

Is it possible to achieve this using asp.net mvc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use reportviewer control in asp.net mvc because it needs postbacks.

But you can use it to generate an image and show it (some googling should give you results about how to accomplish that).

Another option - you can make a hybrid application (web forms + mvc).

And another option - you can try javascript charts. [Google charts](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/) looks good for example.